# Introducing end space

Tags: spacing

Am printing a right adjusted date , but require some space at the end.  Used `\quad` at first, which was not introduced by latex.  Once I add a period `.` at the end, the `\quad` was introduced.

How can I insert the end spacing?

```latex
      \begin{flushright}
        2022, April 23 \quad .
      \end{flushright}
```

Comment: `\hspace*{1em}` instead of `\quad`

Comment: It is good, thank you so very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when TeX ends a paragraph, it removes a trailing space, that's usually unwanted.

Since `\quad` is the same as `\hspace{1em}`, you can add a space that cannot be removed with `\hspace*{1em}`.

On the other hand, `flushright` adds vertical space that may not be desired. You could do

```
\par\noindent\makebox[\columnwidth][r]{2022, April 23\quad}\par
```

Instead of `\par` you can use blank lines, as usual.